# Will libraries used in development work when packaging kivy for android and IOS?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I am making an app for android using kivy and I intend to use the random and sqlite3 and pyperclip libraries so when I use buildozer to make an apk or an ios app will the libraries be used or I can't use any other library except for kivy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happened when you made a simple toy app using those modules?

Comment: Random should not be a problem since it is part of the python standard library. I have seen discussions of sqlite used in a buildozer created apk, but I expect that Pyperclip will not work on Android, since its documentation specifically lists the OS's that it supports, and Android is not mentioned.

Comment: Pyperclip is not an essential library so it's not a big deal if I don't add it but sqlite3 is essential so if it won't work is there any other database library that will work? I will also try to make a simple app to make sure everything works

Comment: Also what about the threading module?

Comment: Threading should not be an issue, and I expect sqlite3 should also work.